# How can I find the underlying db table name from a typed linq query row?

Tags: vb.net, linq, database-schema, datacontext, gettype

In VB.net, I am looking to determine the underlying database table name from a RunTime type Linq query row. I am trying to create a generic routine for deleting rows in ListBoxes, whose object values are query rows. I need the actual table name using DeleteOnSubmit(). It works fine, of course, if I hardcode the table name in, but that's what I am trying to avoid so that I can use a single routine for many listboxes. I just simply hook the KeyUp event. Here's my current code:

```
Private Sub LbxMenuItems_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles LbxMenuItems.KeyUp, LbxCategories.KeyUp
    Dim lbx = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
        Dim msg = "Delete " & lbx.SelectedItems.Count & " selected rows(s)?"
        If MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation) <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
        Dim lbxType As Type = lbx.SelectedItems(0).GetType
        For Each sel In lbx.SelectedItems
            dbh.MenuItems.DeleteOnSubmit(sel)    <--- "MenuItems" IS THE TBL NAME I NEED            Next
        dbh.SubmitChanges()
    End If
End Sub
```

For example:
*lbx.SelectedItems(0).GetType* yields the fullname *"DataAdmin.MenuCategory"*. 
The Table name that I am looking for is MenuCategories. "dbh" is the dataContext qualifier.

I hope that I am explaining this well enough for someone to try to assist. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in understanding that the table name you are looking for depends on the list box in which the user hit delete?  So, list box LbxMenuItems associates with table "MenuItems", while list box LbxCategories associates with table "MenuCategories"?  If that is the case, since the Sub is so small, why not just have 2 different subs, where one handles LbxMenuItems.KeyUp and the other handles LbxCategories.KeyUp?  Then you could even customize them more if you want, such as to say "Dim msg = "Delete " & lbx.SelectedItems.Count & " selected rows(s) from Menu Items?", for example.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Andarta :) Thanks for your reply.  Sure, I could have a sub for all 10 or so ListBoxes but that is exactly what I am trying to sidestep. Plus, the list is growing and a fix to this issue would open doors to many more possibilities down the road. I can still customize the messages even now, with using GetType.Name if needed. Getting the name to the underlying table is key to solving this problem right now. But thank you for your input. :)